# Why is the View import option not shown in the views UI?

Tags: views

I'm trying to export/import a view from a dev site to a qa site. Views UI is enabled. However, when I go to structure>views I don't see the "+ import view" option, only:

"+ Add new view" "+ Add new view from template"

Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 32):

1. If the user you are logged in has the **Administer Views**
   permission, if not then give this permission.
2. Also enable the 'PHP filter' core module.
3. Give the relevant user role the **Use PHP for settings** permission.
4. Paste the below url after your current url and you will see the
   import views page.

   admin/structure/views/import

Comment: the function [views_import_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_import_access/7) makes it pretty clear, as it just checks the other 2 permissions: `administer views` and `use PHP for settings`

Comment: Note that in order to see the "use PHP for settings" permission, the "php" module must be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You should either have sufficient permissions ("administer views" permission) or be logged in as user #1. If you not logging in as user #1, you [will also need to have the permission "use PHP for settings"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11628799/1908609) because of [an issue in Views](https://drupal.org/node/870938).

Then you should be able to go `admin/structure/views/import` and import your view.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're looking in the wrong place. The Export option you used is in the drop down on the View line in your list of Views, while the Import option is at the top of the Views master page as a tab. Took me a while to notice that as I expected the Import option to be in the same drop-down as Export.

Comment: This was totally the right answer for me and don't recall every having to enable extra php modules for this on other sites - usually i expect to find it under Structure > Views in the navigation

Answer (score 0):

Another reason might be that you are using the paranoia module, which disables a lot of php-run features like this.